# Find possible combinations

Tags: c#, search, math

I am trying to make a function that returns all possible combinations of a given set of data.
It's for a hotel yield management problem

There are 3 factors to consider:

- 5 rooms available
- 18 incoming booking requests
- 7 days of booking

If a room is booked for a given day, that room cannot be booked further until it is free the next day.

I believe this might be a simple math problem, however it is not my strongest side, so I ask you for help in order to find the way to create all the possible booking combinations

Best regards

**Edit:**
As requested, here are some additional details:

The goal is to find the highest possible revenue.
All of the 18 requests come on different days, different stay length and room rates, but there are only 5 rooms in this "hotel".

So what I want is to find out how many booking combinations can be done in 7 days with 5 rooms and 18 requests.

Then later I would go through every combination and tally the price to find the best one (exhaustive search)

Does that help?

Comment: you want combinations of what? please provide example set and result for that set

Comment: You should add some example of input and desired output. Helps a lot to find answers.

Comment: You could try looking on the net for simple packing algorithms.  Try a few, see how they work, and if you still have an issue with the code or the algorithm come back and ask about the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would make a brute force attack , because u have a fairly limited combinations. it would be n^3 complexity

Comment: Could you please explain using the 3 sets of data, how do you reach that conclusion?